# Multiple Flat Rate Shipping dependant on category

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

Basicily one category set has a slightly higher delivery cost.

I've installed a Multiple Flat Rate extension but I can't figure out how to set a different flat rate if a product in the shopping cart is from a certain category.

At the moment I've set the flat rate to the higher delivery cost and I'm giving all the other categories a £5 discount, which looks very odd at checkout and on the invoice (especially if the product they purchase is less than £5).

Has anyone done this before, know an extension that will do it or could explain how I could do it?

Comment: On the plus side, I got the tumbleweed bagde for this question. Will look for a different solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used WebShopApps.com's Super Product Rate Extension which allows you to set different shipping prices for each product and assign them into shipping groups. More info here..

http://www.webshopapps.com/super-product-rate.html

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem. One suggestion I found was to use promotional shopping basket rules but unfortunately you cannot set a negative discount - which is a shame.